# how to insert same id's to multiple tables in mysql. using php?

Tags: php, mysql

I've created this to insert to multiple tables, and I want to insert the same ID to both table. ID is auto-incremented in `test` table and I want `test_category` table to take the same ID.

I tried it but don't know where I am doing it wrong and getting an error

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::insert_id() in C:\wamp64\www\Android\include\DbOperations.php on line 27"

Check this pic for detailed error report

[https://www.dropbox.com/s/nuij2o2ac3xp8mz/Untitled4.png?dl=0]

**My php**

```
public function testReg($name, $pin, $a, $b, $ho, $ll, $c, $d){
    $stmt = $this->con->prepare("INSERT INTO `test` (`name`, `pin`) VALUES (?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_Param("ss",$name,$pin);
    if(!$stmt->execute()){
        return 2;
    }
    $stmttst = $this->con->prepare("INSERT INTO `test_category` (`pid`, `name`, `a`, `b`, `ho`, `ll`, `c`, `d`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);");
    $stmttst->bind_Param("isssssss",$stmt->insert_id(),$name,$a,$b,$ho,$ll,$c,$d);
    if ($stmttst->execute()){
        return 1;
    }else{
        return 2;
    }   
}
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "**mysqli::$insert_id**" is an attribute of **mysqli** object and your trying on **$stmt** 
Try Following code will resolve your issue.

```
public function testReg($name, $pin, $a, $b, $ho, $ll, $c, $d){
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare("INSERT INTO `test` (`name`, `pin`) VALUES (?, ?);");
        $stmt->bind_Param("ss",$name,$pin);
        if(!$stmt->execute()){
            return 2;
        }
        $stmttst = $this->con->prepare("INSERT INTO `test_category` (`pid`, `name`, `a`, `b`, `ho`, `ll`, `c`, `d`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);");
        $stmttst->bind_Param("isssssss",$this->con->insert_id(),$name,$a,$b,$ho,$ll,$c,$d);
        if ($stmttst->execute()){
            return 1;
        }else{
        return 2;
        }

   }
```

As of Documents
**mysqli::$insert_id -- mysqli_insert_id** — Returns the auto generated id used in the latest query

So instead of using **$this->con->insert_id()** you can use

```
$var = $this->con;
mysqli_insert_id($var);
```

Comment: it's[mysqli_insert_id($this->con)] working giving an eeror also "Strict standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in C:\wamp64\www\Android\include\DbOperations.php on line 27"

Comment: got it... just need to call it using variable. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting your last inserted id in a variable and then pass it to your 2nd query.

```
public function testReg($name, $pin, $a, $b, $ho, $ll, $c, $d){
$stmt = $this->con->prepare("INSERT INTO `test` (`name`, `pin`) VALUES (?, ?);");
$stmt->bind_Param("ss",$name,$pin);
if(!$stmt->execute()){
   return 2;
  }else{
        //ADDED ESLE AND STORE ID IN VAR
     $lastid=$stmt->insert_id();
  }


$stmttst = $this->con->prepare("INSERT INTO `test_category` (`pid`, `name`, `a`, `b`, `ho`, `ll`, `c`, `d`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);");
$stmttst->bind_Param("isssssss",$lastid,$name,$a,$b,$ho,$ll,$c,$d);
// CHANGED BIND PARAM for last id

if ($stmttst->execute()){
    return 1;
}else{
   return 2;
}
```

}

Also, you shold specify if you are using mysqli or PDO as most people assume you are using PDO as it is most commonly used.

http://php.net/mysqli_multi_query might also help you in this case. Or try creating a second connectionto the BD, not just a 2nd statement.

Comment: further more you could nest your 2nd call inside the else so if the 1st query fails, the 2nd won't run.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for `PDO::lastInsertId`. It returns the ID of the last inserted row. Therefore you can use this in your second query as it will hold the ID of the first. More info here: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php

Comment: I don't understand about how to implement it... can you show me editing my php file?